# How to get wallet address who own certain NFT with certain traits?

Tags: nft

The requirement is like this:

Request:
Get all the wallet address who own the NFT with a trait of 'monkey holding banana'.

Response:
0x123...9056 ;
0xabc...4320 ;
... ;
0x034...afe1

All the wallet addresses above own an NFT who has the trait of 'monkey holding banana'

It don't necessary to be in smart contract, query from off chain code is fine too. If there is certain tools that can do this can be recommended.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would take some time to develop but you could mix this two apis from Alchemy

This one returns all the tokens of the collection with its metadata sorted by tokenId
https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnftsforcollection

```
`withMetadata: true`
```

This one returns the tokenId owned by an address in a collection
https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getownersforcollection

All the required info is there, you just need to digest it

Comment: joining the info returned by this two apis you will get a list of tokens, its owners and its metadata; then you just will need to filter

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work for off-chain, but good enough for my case.